# creating a sum matrix from counts

Tags: r, loops, matrix, sum

I have one matrix of mutation counts, say "counts". This matrix has column names V1, V2,...,Vi,...Vn where not every "i" is there. Thus it can jump, such as V1, V2, V5 say. Further, most of columns have a 0 in them.

I need to create a sum matrix, called "answer", where element i, j is the sum of the number of the number counts at both i and j. At the i, i element it just shows the number of counts at i.

Here's a quick data set up. I already have the correct dimensioned matrix set up in my code called "answer". Thus what I would need to automate are the last several lines where I fill in the matrix.

```
counts <- matrix(data = c(0,2,0,5,0,6,0), nrow = 1, ncol = 7,    dimnames=list("",c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7")))

answer <- matrix(data =0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("V2","V4","V6"),c("V2","V4","V6")))

answer[1,1] <- 2
answer[1,2] <- 7
answer[1,3] <- 8
answer[2,1] <- 7
answer[2,2] <- 5
answer[2,3] <- 11
answer[3,1] <- 8
answer[3,2] <- 11
answer[3,3] <- 6
```

I understand I can do this with 2 nested for loops, but surely there must be a better way no? Thanks!

Comment: Is `counts` always a 1-dimensional matrix as shown here?

Comment: yes, it is. To be specific, counts represents all the amino acids in a protein. Each amino acid can have 0 or more mutations. Thus counts is always 1D, from the first AA in the protein to the last.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from counts to answer. In particular, shouldn't V6 be zero and therefore not in the output? (Did you mean V2, V4, V5 for the names in the output?)

Comment: Slight typo, I have fixed it. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done with the right use of `expand.grid` and `rowSums`:

```
n = counts[, counts > 0]
answer = matrix(rowSums(expand.grid(n, n)), nrow=length(n), dimnames=list(names(n), names(n)))
diag(answer) = n
```

To show how it works, `n` would end up being:

```
V2 V4 V5 
 2  5  6
```

and `expand.grid(n, n)` would be:

```
  Var1 Var2
1    2    2
2    5    2
3    6    2
4    2    5
5    5    5
6    6    5
7    2    6
8    5    6
9    6    6
```

The last line (`diag`) is necessary because otherwise the diagonal would be twice the original vector (adding `2+2`, `5+5`, or `6+6`).